# VitualEnv in python : Access Denied

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am running Windows 8.1 with python 2.7.11, 3.4.3, 3.5.1. Only python 2.7 is added to path. Im trying to create a virtual environment using the following command in cmd (with administrative privilages)

```
virtualenv -p B:\Apps\Python\2.7 sympy2.7
```

It results in the following error

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter B:\Apps\Python\2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "b:\apps\python\2.7\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "b:\apps\python\2.7\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals
File "B:\Apps\Python\2.7\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "b:\apps\python\2.7\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 665, in main popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
File "b:\apps\python\2.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__ errread, errwrite)
File "b:\apps\python\2.7\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

I tried implemeting the solution given in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793650/using-virtualenv-with-multiple-python-versions-on-windows) but none of them work. For eg, the command

```
py -2.7 -m virtualenv sympy2.7
```

or this command,

```
virtualenv -p B:\Apps\Python\2.7\python.exe sympy2.7
```

results in

```
New python executable in A:\Programming\Open Source\Sympy\environments\sympy2.7\Scripts\python.exe
ERROR: The executable "A:\Programming\Open Source\Sympy\environments\sympy2.7\Scripts\python.exe" could not be run: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the solution was to refer to the executable file instead of the folder. The 'Access is denied' error message is quite misleading.

```
C:\Installs\Python_3.8>virtualenv -p C:\Installs\Python_3.8 tensorflow_env
# Output: RuntimeError: failed to query C:\Installs\Python_3.8 with code 13 err: 'Access is denied'

C:\Installs\Python_3.8>virtualenv -p C:\Installs\Python_3.8\python.exe tensorflow_env
# Output: created virtual environment CPython3.8.0.final.0-64 in 2504ms
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in virtualenv due to spaces in the path. It was incorrectly quoting the path to the newly created `python.exe`, causing it to not be found.

[pypa/virtualenv#936](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/936) is the fix for the issue, but the workaround is to only create virtual environments in paths without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in virtualenv due to spaces in the path.
Corrent the whole path to the env without any space
eg: E:\Works\project_2017

Answer (score 0):

Use this command `virtualenv -p "B:\Apps\Python\2.7 sympy2.7"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `py -m virtualenv -p python3 mytest`