# Install TensorFlow Object Detection on Windows Problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, pyarrow

I am trying to install Tensor Flow Object Detection on Windows 10.

**Resource:** https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-on-windows-2eef9b7ae869

After running these steps, we are receiving the errors below. It is stalling on pyarrow.
How can this be fixed?

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
python -m pip install .
```

[image]

```
  Error: Collecting pyarrow<3.0.0,>=0.15.1
  Using cached pyarrow-2.0.0.tar.gz (58.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\joe.k.smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\joe.k.smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\joe.k.smith\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b29td69q\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (1950 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
  Collecting cython>=0.29
    Using cached Cython-0.29.23-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)
  Collecting numpy==1.16.0
```

**Additional Resources:**

https://medium.com/riow/tensorflow-object-detection-on-windows-ad10bfde217c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about that error, but for Tensorflow in general, if you go to [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install), you'll see that, as of this writing, the only supported version of python are 3.6 - 3.8. It sounds like for tensorflow/models,  you might do well to use 3.7. You will want to make sure you have a compatible version of pip as well.

Comment: interesting , I have basic tensorflow functionalities running, linear equation guessing, natural language, however object detection does not work, let me test with earlier python version

Comment: I personally have had some really good results using [their docker container on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow), coupled with WSL2. It took a while to figure out I'm pretty happy with the result.

Comment: @mattsmith5 hmm, yeah Idk. But  have hit the "too new python version" problem a couple times before and seen other people hit it for tensorflow itself. Also, you want to be aware of what is supported for TF1 vs TF2. But I don't know of a good way of telling the requirements for tensorflow/models/object-detection, other than just running the setup file like you did. Or using docker.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found one of my non-docker installations, and it's using python 3.7 and tensorflow 1.15.2.

Comment: this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/22793687/15435022 py -3.4 -m venv c:\path\to\wherever\you\want\it  , still researching

Comment: I posted this follow up question, maybe you can help, thanks , I'n getting further https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259900/tensorflow-installation-on-windows-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tens